# Unable to Disable Touchpad on HP

Tags: windows-10, synaptics-touchpad

**I can't disable touch pad on my HP 250 G6 Notebook PC.**

OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro

Version 10.0.18362 Build 18362

System Model HP 250 G6 Notebook PC

BIOS Version/Date Insyde F.52, 3/4/2019

I have tried doing the following:

1) There are no obvious **on/off or Fshortcut buttons** on my notebook.  Some HP laptops have the touchpad on/off hidden inside the touchpad itself and when you hold your finger in the top left corner for 5 seconds you are able to disable/enable the touchpad.  I've tried doing this and there is no illuminating light on my touchpad to indicate this functionality exists on my laptop nor is there an F9 shortcut for touchpad.

2) I've tried going to **control panel** > mouse > hover over touchpad and right-click and there is NO option to disable the touchpad.
[see pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIxdn.png)
By selecting "Properties" for the Touchpad the option to disable touchpad is grayed out. 
[see pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/089qR.png)

3) I've tried going into the **BIOS Settings** by pressing f10 upon start and I cannot find ANY option to disable "internal pointing device" anywhere in BIOS. Note: the BIOS was recently updated. With the previous BIOS version I was able to go in and find the "internal pointing device" option and disable it which is how I had my touchpad off in the past.

4) I've tried uninstalling the **device driver** but upon restart Windows re-installs the driver automatically.

Comment: What happens if you double tap the top left corner, instead of holding it? That's the shortcut for some HP laptops.

Comment: Have you successfully disabled the touchpad?

Comment: @wrecclesham, absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: @John, no I have not.

Comment: Then i think you cannot disable it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Touchpad or PS/2 mouse](https://superuser.com/questions/89196/disable-touchpad-or-ps-2-mouse)

Answer (score -2):

If there is no TrackPoint button (I do not think there is), then you cannot disable the TouchPad. That is the main and only mouse-like input device.